# I need assistance with Opera compatibility

Tags: opera

On my website, Opera is messing up my homepage, but no other browser is doing the same thing.
On this page http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/ the first song under random songs always disappears so if anyone could help me solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.  Also in Opera, when I hover over the thumbnails on the homepage, the greyish divs are supposed to change to black divs.  This feature works on all other browsers but Opera.  Again, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's preferable to ask specific questions, perhaps with a jsfiddle/jsbin, than make people visit the site, view source, figure out where/what everything is, etc.

Comment: I don't see any of the problems you mention in a test build of Opera 12 - what version do you use?

Comment: How do I check the version?  I have never used Opera before, I just downloaded it to make sure that all browsers were compatible with my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your javascript:

```
function boxOffHover(box) {
box.style.background = '#ABABAB';
box.style.color='white';
}

function boxOnHover(box) {
box.style.background ='#404040';
box.style.color='white';
}
```

And html:

```
<div id="box3" align="center"> ...
<div id='box' align='center' onmouseover='boxOnHover(this);' onmouseout='boxOffHover(this);'>
```

I would point out to some of the more extreme things:

1) there is really a bug in Opera 11.5x, not redrawing properly. Yet, this should not make you happy, because your code sucks. And here are three main reasons why.

2) Use css. Its so much simpler to do mouseovers with, especially when compared to using javascript -  `#box:hover { background-color: #404040; }`

3) You are required to use unique IDs for html elements. This means - do not use `id="box3` several times in same document.

4) [Indent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) you code. It will be much easier for you and other people to read.